# Under which folder should I persist a non-user-specific DB?

Tags: database, fhs

Where is it customary/appropriate for me to persist my DB? Should it be:

- Under `/var/lib/` ?
- Under `/var/db/` ?
- Elsewhere?

(I'm assuming it doesn't matter which DB it is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your db holds variable data and not program configuration, and according to the fhs standard, the place should be either `/var/lib/yourapp` or `/var/lib/misc`.

Now, if it contains only configuration for the program *on the computer*, maybe its place is in `/etc/yourapp`.

If it is both, dont really know.

I didnt see `/var/db` in the standart, so i assume it is a custom folder, which isnt advised.

> Applications must never create or require special files or subdirectories in the root directory. Other locations in the FHS hierarchy provide more than enough flexibility for any package.

[Related Fhs standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION)
(fhs stands for file hierarchy standard)

Comment: In the file you linked to, `/var/db` is mentioned in footnote 39. But the way its mentioned sort of gives me the answer. I just felt the name "lib" doesn't really sound right, as there's nothing "library"ish about my DB.